Should I adjust for time for different baseline entry time in an observational study?
Suppose I have a dataset with n waves. I will select samples based on a specific criterion (e.g., wave i with event=0; wave i+1 with event=1). Therefore, each individual's entry time is different. However, because I have n waves, some people may enter the study at the same time. Now, if I take wave i (depending on individuals) as baseline and use wave i+1 as the outcome, do I need to account for time effects? I suspect there might be period effects (such as age-period-cohort effects, etc).
Update:
I have tried 'Jomo' with my own dataset (7 binary variables, 5 continuous variables, 20k+ rows). The speed is extremely slow, is there any other methods to use instead of 'Jomo'?
